# Using statement best practice

Tags: c#, using

It may be a silly question, but since I can't give it an answer by my own, I will ask it here.

Let we have a module that we want to use in an http handler (the web app is written in C# using ASP.NET) and let that this module implements the `IDisposable` interface. Then a common approach is to 
use the module as below:

```
using(var module = new ModuleName(param1, param2, param3))
{

}
```

Is it better to place any code to variables that we are going to use only inside the body of this `using` statement  or before this. In terms of code:

Is it better (and why) the first approach or the second approach:

**first approach**

```
using(var module = new ModuleName(param1, param2, param3))
{
    int a = Request.GetParam<int>("aNumber");
    string b = Request.GetParam<string>("bString");
    // and other parameters contained to the http request
}
```

**second approach**

```
int a = Request.GetParam<int>("aNumber");
string b = Request.GetParam<string>("bString");
// and other parameters contained to the http request

using(var module = new ModuleName(param1, param2, param3))
{

}
```

*If there isn't any technical reason -and it is an opinion based decision- that we should prefer the first approach to second approach or vice versa, please let me know, in order to delete my post.*

Comment: Always prefer lesser scope to avoid confusions. So if variables are not required outside of `using` put them inside using. btw question is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on if you need those variables outside of the scope of the `using`-statement. If so, you need to declare them outside anyway. If not, declare them in the `using`.

Why? It's all about readability, fail-safety and refactoring.

This is true not only for the `using` but scopes and variable declaration in general. Read:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/variable-declaration-closer-to-usage-vs-declaring-at-the-top-of-method
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them

Comment: True enough, but this is of course general to any code block, not just `using`.

Comment: @RegEdit: that's why i've posted the links to questions which are not related only to the `using`-statement but _scopes_ and variable declaration in general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, so you have posted links, but I think it's helpful to state it explicitly as you've now done. In any case, bullets following `It's all about readability, fail-safety and refactoring` might be assumed to be about readability, fail-safety and refactoring.