# Is it good practice to declare object inside block scope(Do and Loop,For [Each] and Next,If and End If etc) Condition

Tags: vb.net

Is it good practice to declare object inside [`block scope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) Condition

```
If item.DocType = 1 Then

     Dim objass As Assignment = DBFactory.GetAssignmentDB.AssignmentGetByID(vis.AssignmentID)                   

End If
```

OR should i declare object outside the if condition and then do assignment inside

```
 Dim objass As Assignment

 If item.DocType = 1 Then

     objass = DBFactory.GetAssignmentDB.AssignmentGetByID(vis.AssignmentID)

 End If
```

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979493/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/variable-declaration-closer-to-usage-vs-declaring-at-the-top-of-method and (replace `using` with `if`) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25077014/284240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That entirely depends on the scenario.

If you want to use the variable within the condition only, then declare it inside the condition. If you want the variable to be used outside of the If statement, then it's scope must extend to outside the condition.

There is no 'good practice' for all scenarios. Sometimes it'll be inside, sometimes not - depends on it's usage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1t0wsc67.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is good coding style to declare variables  in the smalles scope they are used.

I.e. in your example it depends if you want to access ´ass´ outside the if condition. - If you declare ´ass` inside it, you cannot access it outside.